# Jersey Vs Spring for REST webservices

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

( trying rewording as per suggestions )

I would like to know which of the two would be less learning curve for writing RESTful web services? ( for someone who dont know both)
I really don't need web MVC .

I would like easy mapping from URL to java function, JSON/XML output options, avoid malicious input from user, translation support for strings etc and low latency for response with data coming from MySQL.

I am looking for the simplicity too.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simplicity, use Java EE 6+. You can start RESTful programming using JAX-RS API (javax.ws.rs) without any need to set up Jersey or Spring.

Jersey:
Pros: Standard API (JAX-RS)
Cons: MVC support is less richer than Spring MVC.

Spring:
Pros: Many features, many documents, active community.
Cons: Many rules to learn.

Comment: thanks for the input .. i will try with JAX-RS API first then